# significance test for changes between two groups?

Tags: significance

I sampled 1000 people in 2018 and then 1000 people in 2019. 
For brand A, 5% of participants like the brand in 2018, and 8% of participants like the brand in 2019. 
For brand B, 25% of participants like the brand in 2018, and 29% of participants like the brand in 2019.

So people who like the brand grow 3% for Brand A, and 4% for Brand B, and I want to know if this 1% difference is significant or not, what's the right method to do the test?

Thank you!

Comment: I think I figured it out. As long as 3% and 4% are statistically significant, then the difference is significant. So a two proportion Z test will do the work.